# Proper Way To Use kotlinx.serialization To Serialize Kotlin Implementation Of Java Abstract Class

Tags: kotlin, serialization, polymorphism

I am trying to use the [kotlin standard serialization library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization), and I am running into an issue because my knowledge of how Kotlin and Java work together is limited.

I've have defined abstract class inside a Java library, that looks similar to the following.

```java
public abstract class A {
  private final String s;

  public A(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }
}
```

I then am trying to extend that class in a Kotlin package and make the result serializable.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class B(s: String) : A(s)
```

However, the @Serializable annotation will only serialize the s property of by B class if it is marked as a val/var. When I do that, using something like Json.decode does not work, as @Serializable will only instantiate the Kotlin field, and Kotlin generates Bytecode with 2 fields, `A.s` and also `B.s`.

Marking as such doesn't really make sense anyways, unless I could mark `s` in `A` as abstract, and override the property in Kotlin. Unfortunately, this is not possible in Java.

Do you have any idea what the correct pattern to this is?

Comment: I would be at least a little surprised if this were possible.